# Copy only files inside a folder in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to to a gulp task which copies all files inside a folder to another folder

```
gulp.task('copy-fonts', ['unzip'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./gulp-tmp/**/fonts/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('fonts'));
});
```

The problem is, the name of the directory after `gulp-tmp` varies, so I had to use `**` there.

So the result ends up like `/fonts/[randomFolderName]/fonts/[the files]`

Where what I want is `/fonts/[the files]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-flatten).

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.src('./gulp-tmp/**/fonts/*')
  .pipe(flatten())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('fonts'));
```

Comment: this is recommended answer.

Answer (score 6):

I use simple code without external libs, for example:

```
gulp.src('./src/fonts/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/build/fonts'));
```

or only html files:

```
gulp.src('./src/templates/*.html')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/build/templates'));
```

Comment: Excellent...thanks!


I was looking around to find out why just having an asterisk was bringing in the directories too:


```javascript
gulp.src('app/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist.root));
```


I'd mistakenly thought that I needed the double asterices in order to recurse, but seeing your solution made me realise that I can do this:


```javascript
gulp.src('app/*.*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist.root));
```


I guess it will still bring in directories with a dot in the name...but anyway, thanks.